# How to download csv file from S3 bucket into numpy array

Tags: numpy, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a csv file in an AWS S3 bucket. How do I download the CSV and assign it to a numpy array?

[Using python 3.6/boto3]

I've tried various forms including:

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=region)
    obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)

    with io.BytesIO(obj.get()["Body"].read()) as f:
       # rewind the file
       f.seek(0)

    arr_data = numpy.load(f)

    arr_data = numpy.genfromtxt('https://BUCKETNAME.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/folder/infile.csv',dtype='str',delimiter=',')
```

This also doesn't work

Essentially I'm trying to replicate in S3:
        arr_data = np.genfromtxt('path...input.csv',dtype='str',delimiter=',')

Answer (score 0):

I was able to convert a csv to a numpy array using pandas in-between... not sure if that's what you're looking for. But here's how I did it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_location = 's3://<path>'
data = pd.read_csv(data_location)
data_numpy = data.value.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks but I should have made clearer, not using pandas...only using numpy.